# TikZ. Is there a way to alternate path to be drawn basing on some condition?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, paths

What I want is to connect nodes by stepped (horizontal-vertical-horizontal, hvh) path if they have different y-coordinate, and by straight line if they are on the same level.

Costruction of the only hvh-path in any case gives unwanted deviation of curve in the point where should stepping have happened as if nodes had different y-coordinate.

See below the LaTeX-code I try (there are also different ways I've tested that are commented out by now):

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox, ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,chains,shapes.multipart,backgrounds,positioning,fit,calc}

\newcommand{\setup}{
    \tikzset{
        node distance=5mm and 3cm,
        block/.style={rectangle, draw, thick},
        every edge/.style={->, rounded corners, thick, draw,
            to path={
                let \p1=(\tikztostart.east),
                    \p2=($ (\tikztostart.east) + (1cm,0) $),
                    \p3=(\tikztotarget.west) in
                %\ifnumequal{\y1}{\y2}{(\p1) -- (\p3)}{(\p1) -- (\p2) |- (\p3)}
                %(\p1) -- (\p2) \ifnumcomp{\y2}{=}{\y3}{-- (\p3)}{|- (\p3)}
                %\ifthenelse{\equal{\y1}{\y2}}{(\p1) -- (\p3)}{(\p1) -- (\p2) |- (\p3)}
                (\p1) -- (\p2) |- (\p3)
                \tikztonodes
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \setup

    \node[block] (A) {System A};
    \node[block] (B) [above right=of A] {System B};
    \node[block] (C) [right=of A] {System C};
    \node[block] (D) [below right=of A] {System D};

    \path
    (A) edge (B)
        edge (C)
        edge (D);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It is important that I want to keep the conciseness of the main code in tikzpicture environment. So the test of nodes being on the same level should be incapsulated somewhere inside the edge style (posibly .code?). There shouldn't be any such logic exposed in picture's main code, because I tend it to be declarative.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks to Altermundus and Martin Scharrer. I've ended up with following variant:

```
(\p1) -- (\p2) \ifdim\y2=\y3  -- \else |- \fi (\p3)
```

Comment: I feel like this would be a good use of a `pgf` *decoration*.  But when I started to code it up I realized it would take more code then the answers you've already got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this : (I don't know `etoolbox`) I modified the code with the help of Martin !

```
\newcommand{\setup}{
    \tikzset{
        node distance=5mm and 3cm,
        block/.style={rectangle, draw, thick},
        every edge/.style={->, rounded corners, thick, draw,
            to path={
                let \p1=(\tikztostart.east),
                    \p2=($ (\tikztostart.east) + (1cm,0) $),
                    \p3=(\tikztotarget.west) in 
          \ifdim\y1=\y2   (\p1) -- (\p3) \else (\p1) -- (\p2) |- (\p3)\fi
               (\p1) -- (\p2) 
          \ifdim\y2=\y3  -- (\p3) \else |- (\p3)\fi       
                (\p1) -- (\p2) |- (\p3)
                \tikztonodes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are comparing `\y` with `1` here. Note that `\y`, `\x` and `\p` are all macros which take the index as argument. The `\y1` is short for `\y{1}` and you can also take any other label you want (within reason). **Replace** `\ifx` with `\ifdim` and put an `=` between the `\yn`s and it might work.

Comment: @Martin You are right ! I never use the facility `\p1` ... I need to memorize your comment !!

Comment: @Altermundus your suggestion, concerning @Martin Scharrer's remarks, did the trick!

Comment: Well, I'm new to StackExchange, so I'm unsure whether should I accept Altermundus's solution or, contrary, having no needed result after direct application of his answer, it should be marked as unuseful?

Comment: Yeah, you got it :)

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not very old to StackExchange and  I don't know what you need to do. I just hope my answer helped you but your question and comment from Martin have been very helpful for me. Thanks to Martin !