# TikZ: How to compare approximate equality of dimensions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, dimensions, comparison, pgfmath

When scaling `tikzpicture` using option `scale`, some points that had equal coordinates appear to be shifted a little bit. So the precise comparision `\ifdim \y1 = \y2` will not do anymore.

I'm aware of `\pgfmathapproxequalto`, but the problem is that dimensions are not plain numbers.

Comment: I was not aware of `\pgfmathapproxequalto`, but know that using dimensions instead of plain numbers is not a problem with the `\pgfmath...` macros. You can simply use it with dimensions: `\pgfmathapproxequalto{1pt}{1pt}` or even mixed: `\pgfmathapproxequalto{1pt}{1}`. Did you tried that and got an error? It works OK in my little tests.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, you are right, it seems to work. I messed up with `\the` macro (`\the\y1`), which led me to errors. This problem is the consequence of this topic (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15107/tikz-is-there-a-way-to-alternate-path-to-be-drawn-basing-on-some-condition). When scaling, I get the same artifacts, even when I check the points to be on horizontal or vertical line.

Comment: @Dmitry: You should put your edit into an answer instead and then accept it so that this question won't appear unanswered.

Comment: @TH: Yeah, you are right, and I will do that shortly. There's restriction for me (being quite a new user) to self-answer only after 24 hours. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: The 24 hours accept-your-own-answer is active for all users, not just the new ones. And with 120rep you should be free of all new-user restrictions relevant for posting.

Comment: @Martin: Well, before editing my question, I failed to post an answer with notificaiton that I have to wait for sometime (do not remember exact period). By now, yes, I have to wait, as it says, for 2 days beforce I am able to accept my own answer.

Comment: True. I just wanted to point out that this is for all users, not just for new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `\pgfmathapproxequalto` uses fixed precision of `0.0001`, but in my case scaling was so distorting that finally I had to set precision to `0.01`. So, the solution was to use `\pgfmathparse{abs(\y1 - \y2) <= 0.01}`.

By the way, I have to call this macro from inside of `pgfextra`, because this condition is used to alter path construction on the fly.